# JavaScript Multiply condition statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I've got js function that selects report number from multiply parameters (2 checkboxes, 3 dropdown fields), and I got a very big condition statement like this

```
    switch(ReportNumDrop)
    {
       case 0: NumberReport = IsDropDownValue == 0 ? 1034: 1033;
       break;

       case 1: if(CheckBoxChecked)
               {
                   NumberReport = IsDropDownValue == 0 ? 1022: 1021;

               }
               else
               {
                 NumberReport = IsDropDownValue == 0 ? 1011: 1012;
               }
               break;
          ....
          //SimilarStatement with another rep number
          ....
          case 6: if(DropDownCondition2)
                  {
                      NumberReport = SecondDropDownValue == '*' ? 1045: 1044;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    NumberReport = ThirdDropDownValue == 0 ? 1055: 1054;
                  }
           break;
           default: break;
          }
```

So,it's like the finite state graph, but what is the simplest way to refactor this so it can be read wihout blood from eyes.

(i think it's similar to command pattern form GOF)

Also, code isn't mine

P.S C# can be used to form this number via async call

Comment: Misprinted in 6 case, there another controls used

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe?

```
var fs = [
  [function () { ReportNumDrop == 0 && IsDropDownValue == 0 }, 1034],
  [function () { ReportNumDrop == 0 && IsDropDownValue != 0 }, 1033],
  ...
];
```

then iterate over this array to find an element which has a function that returns `true`.

Comment: Where will be a lot of copypaste cos of using conditions with one where one param is differ

Comment: remember DFAs? you can implement a DFA if you do not like this one. have a state, and transitions defined as functions similar to the above. in this case you will have fewer repetitions. but is it worth it?

Comment: what do you mean? what bicycle?

Comment: maybe there is simple ready to go solution, or some jquery plugin for this task. (bicycle - is like Create a bicycle (= )